# Cordova Java Ionic Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am pretty new to this platform(Cordova,Android). I am trying Mobile App Setup section from this link: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/cloud/MCS_Packaged_Apps/EBS%20Self-Service%20Apps/ebs-self-service/ebs-self-service-v2.html#section5s14

I get different kind of errors while running the commands mentioned in above link, section Mobile App Setup.

Finally I am running the Command : grunt build --platform=android

Error: 
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/home/chirag/project/android/MobileSelfServiceSolutionV2/selfservice-ui/hybrid/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js'

> > Unhandled error. (The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.)

Java version on my system:
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Node: v11.0.0

Cordova: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Ionic CLI 4.3.1

I have done enough research and tried many solution from stack and other forums but no luck. Any help is much more appreciated. Let me know if required any more details. Thanks!

Comment: have you followed all steps carefully? What I believe you are missing some installation of any component.

Comment: I have followed resolved all the steps successfully except this: yo oraclejet:restore. And it is giving this error: chirag@chirag-Latitude-3580:~$ yo oraclejet:restore
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'paths' of null